# включить скрипт в тело

Tags: javascript

включить скрипт в тело
Помогите! Создать 2 страницы. Для первой страницы включить скрипт в тело, для второй – внешний файл. С помощью скрипта вывести сообщения о типе подключения скрипта и авторе работы. Для хранения информации об авторе задать переменные. Очень нужна ваша помощь! Если можно с объяснениями плиз!!!!! Сыну в академии задали, только начали эту тему! Надеюсь на вашу помощь!

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что выполнять работу для третьих лиц - это как-то уж слишком.

Comment: Дорогая мамочка, позвольте вашему сыну вырасти и стать самостоятельным. Тем более сын не в школе какой-то учится, а в академии... И если он не решился сам задать вопрос, то может быть уже давно все сделано?

Comment: Ну тогда совет - не просить и брать готовое, а для начала почитать литературу. Хотя бы [это](http://javascript.ru/tutorial), [там же](http://javascript.ru/tutorial/foundation/start) можно было найти подробное описание того, что от вас требуют. А вопросы задавать надо уже конкретно по неясным местам.

Comment: @tania-31 "Учебников у них нет, ", простите, что? Интернет - вот вам учебник, а когда родители делают работу за детей, то это же просто нелогично! Чему тогда он научится? гуглим "javascript, основы" и читаем помаленьку и всё!

Comment: Добрый день ! Нужно составить легкий тест на 5 вопросов используя   js! Может есть у кого то ссылки на уроки по этой теме!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну как я понял, просят банальщину вроде такого вот...

page1.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Пример скрипта в теле страницы</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var author = "вася";

        alert("скрипт в теле");
        alert(author);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

page2.html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Пример скрипта во внешнем файле</title>
    <script src="external.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

external.js:

```
var author = "вася";

alert("скрипт в теле");
alert(author);
```

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Интерпретатору чхать - весь код в одном пространстве, узнать что подключено, а что нет - не представляется возможным.
Возможно так:

```
// External.js
var ext = 'Я внешний файл, ура, товарищи!';

// Index.html
...
<head>
...
<script src='External.js'></script>
...
<script>
  var internal = 'А я и так внутри :)';

  window.onload = function(){
    alert(ext);
    alert(internal);
  }
</script>
...
</head>
```